# Why does the East Tal-Tal Heights Warp Point not work?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

I am between Catfish's Maw and Face Shrine, but went exploring and came across the warp point location in the north east of the map (near Eagle's Tower). It did not activate for me when I stood on it.

According to e.g. [this site](https://www.gamepur.com/guide/43541-legend-zelda-links-awakening-switch-warp-point-locations.html),

> To activate a warp point, all you have to do is find it.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get it to activate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the warp points that has to be dug out of the ground. Just use the shovel and it will appear properly.